# Should I use a modal prompt/dialog for user input?

Tags: input, input-fields, modal-windows

For an application for a teacher, who has to enter marks obtained in the class test for 60 students; what is the best way to get input from them to ensure accuracy, speed and convenience?

My proposal (which I don't see in many applications today) is to prompt user with a modal, with Student Name/id and an input box. As soon the user presses `Enter`, the system presents a new dialog to get the marks of next student.

Is this good UI/UX design practice?

[image: When user clicks Ok, the next popup is displayed with details of the next student.]

Answer (score 2):

One problem I thought exists with this approach has to do with the order in which the teacher needs to enter the scores.   If she has a stack of graded tests, she'd need to sort them before using this procedure.   It might be nice to be able to type part of the student's name and have matches immediately displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as a former teacher filling in marks is something typically done after all of the papers/assignments have been graded.

Thus one has ~30 scores to input, and the stack of assignments is in the order the pile is in (order ~= submission order)

As such, the closer to a grid like (think Excel) format the better.

In fact for speed I'd often re-order assignments to match the grid then punch in score (enter), score (enter), score (enter), etc.

Just be sure whatever solution you come up with doesn't hinder the user's speed (eg if each score loads a popup and requires dismissing and re-launching the user will tire quickly.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it seems usable** but we cannot give you valid answer because we don't know the exact context.
The best advice is to implement this approach and give it to real teachers to use it. Also, you can go and do observations to see how the process goes.

A possible problem for the teachers would be to remember the name of each student. **She might not remember who was John McDowell** and if picture of the student is available or the exam that she is marking would be useful.